# How will I get a birthdate (year,month,day) with carbon on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to convert a birthdate to format year, month, day with carbon on laravel 5.4

according the carbon's documentation the method to get an age on blade is this

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($bday)->age
```

but the result is '0' and i want this

```
$bday =  '2017-10-01' =  0 year 1 month 4 days
```

Thank you and sorry my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carbon's `age` returns just the number of years in a person's age, as you have seen.

In your model, you could set up a `getAge` method that will return the age in years, months and days:

```
public function getAge(){
    return $this->birthdate->diff(Carbon::now())
         ->format('%y years, %m months and %d days');
}
```

You can call your model in the view as `$user->getAge()`